# Привести число в нормальный вид на JS

Tags: javascript

Есть число. Например **0.66111**

Как средствами js получить - **0.6**?

Comment: http://javascript.ru/Math

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function cut(value, precision){ 
    var dec = Math.pow(10, precision)    
    return Math[(value > 0) ? 'floor' : 'ceil'](value * dec) / dec
}
```

Для вашего случая просто примените `cut(0.66111, 1)`

**P.S.** Хочу обратить внимание, что я написал функцию обрезания числа, а не его округления

**UPD.** Учитывая замечание [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), функция доработана для использования с отрицательными числами.

Comment: omg: (0.66111).toFixed(2);

Comment: @Яковлев Андрей, в вашем случае `.toFixed(precision)` избыточен

Comment: @lampa, будьте внимательнее - Spectre в своём ответе пояснил почему так нельзя

Comment: @lampa, задача автора из *0.66111* получить *0.6*. Вашим методом будет *0.7*... Чувствуете разницу. Вы ошиблись.

Comment: @Spectre, спасибо поправил

Comment: @Яковлев Андрей, все хорошо. Главное, чтобы не делало из 0.6 - 1. Ваш ответ считаю вернее. Спасибо! :)

Comment: @Яковлев Андрей, а вы хоть пробовали протестить, что получится? С какой это радости toFixed начнет скруглять значение? о_О

Comment: @ModaL "Ваш ответ считаю вернее. Спасибо! :)" Тогда советую несколько раз пропустить число через функцию, а вдруг?...

Comment: @lampa, пробывал. toFixed возвратил 0.7, тоже не дело. Поэтому код @Яковлев Андрей более точен для меня.

Comment: @lampa, а Вам за участие, в Ваших трех вопросах понажимал палец вверх. Ваши очки увеличились на 30 :))

Comment: надо ещё отдельно обрабатывать случай отрицательного аргумента. попробуйте ваш код для `-0.66111`. ([подсказка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125715/javascript-trunc-function))

Comment: @VladD,  отрицательные значения не допускаются, соответственно не нужно :)

Comment: да.. получается для отрицательных надо использовать `Math.ceil` вместо `Math.floor`

Answer (score 4):

Элементарно же:

```
+0.66111.toFixed(1) // 0.7

+(0.66111.toString().substr(0,3)) // 0.6
```

- [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)
- [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Answer (score 3):

[[@ModaL](/users/6646/modal)](/users/6646/modal) вот я лох, ну держите тогда:

```
Math.floor(0.66111*10)/10
```

Как самый короткий :D

Comment: Еще +10 к Вашим очкам) Везет же))

Comment: @ModaL И вам не хворать, +100 :-)

Comment: @lampa, ухххх! Вот это щедрость! Буду должен ^^

Comment: чем ваш ответ отличается от ответа тов. @Яковлев Андрей?

Comment: @Spectre Он короче, и всего лишь :-)

Comment: На мой взгляд самый простой и годный ответ, в javascript чем меньше код, тем быстрее грузится страница. Из таких мелочей в общей картине создается огромная портянка, которую можно ужать раза в 2.